# Weak Entity with Primary Key?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, database-theory

I have the following E-R diagram to refer to:
[image]

I have a question posed to me that entity 4 IS a weak entity due to one of its relations. However, from what I see, entity 4 has a composite primary key made up of l, m, and n, none of which are partial keys and weak entities would not have any primary keys, only foreign or partial keys. I only see the relationship between entity 3 and 4 somehow causing it to be a weak entity, but I am unsure. I saw [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188335/can-a-weak-entity-have-a-primary-key) post already, but it almost re-iterated what I was thinking unless I understood it wrong.

Comment: And what is exactly your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.